# Loop subfolders with different parent folder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder structure that consists of multiple client names on the root of a drive.  Within each of these client folders I have the same subfolder.  What I'd like to do is loop through each of the client folders and for a specific sub folder within each of the client folders, I'd like to set specific permissions using the `Get-Acl` command in PowerShell.

I need the script to ignore the client's name (`JOHN`, `PETER`) but loop through each to change the permission to the `PRIVATE` folder or all folders within the `Special File` folder:

> S:\CLIENT FILES\JOHN\Special File\PRIVATE
>   S:\CLIENT FILES\PETER\Special File\PRIVATE

Comment: Please show an example of your code and where you are having trouble.

Comment: I got it (without the permissions yet): $root = "S:\CLIENT FILES"

ForEach ($dir in (Get-Item -Path "$root\*\Special File\PRIVATE" | ?{$_.PSIsContainer})){

echo $dir

 If (!(Test-Path -Path "$dir\Hello")) {
        
        New-Item -Path "$dir" -Name "SPENCER" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

        }
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain your code in a readable form. Comments are just for ehm comments. Single code lines could be enclosed in backticks `\``. See also [format comments](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: `Get-ChildItem "C:\Client Files\*\Special File"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` allows the use of wildcards in the `-Path` parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\CLIENT FILES\*\Special File\PRIVATE' | Get-Acl
```